# How do you hide information e.g. download location etc when using WGET

Tags: linux, wget

How exactly do you hide information when downloading with WGET e.g. is there a parameter that can hide the download location, or extra information and only show the important information such as progress of the download?

Comment: Found the answer - use the -nw switch

Answer (score 2):

Use the no verbose mode (`-nv`)

```
wget -nv <url>
```